# Trying to import sql data into visual studio web form database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to import the following data:

```
    INSERT INTO shifts (shift_id, shift_facility_id, shift_user_id, shift_start_time, shift_replacement, shift_request_replacement) VALUES
(1, 57, '1', '2017-05-19 00:00:00.000000', NULL, NULL),
(2, 57, '1', '2017-05-19 12:00:00.000000', NULL, NULL),
(3, 57, '1', '2017-05-20 00:00:00.000000', NULL, NULL),
(4, 57, '1', '2017-05-20 12:00:00.000000', NULL, NULL),
(5, 57, '2', '2017-05-21 00:00:00.000000', NULL, NULL),
(62, 59, '6', '2017-05-19 00:00:00.000000', NULL, NULL),
(64, 60, '4', '2017-05-19 00:00:00.000000', NULL, NULL);
```

in the following database:

(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

```
CREATE TABLE shifts (

shift_id int NOT NULL, 
  shift_facility_id int NOT NULL,
  shift_user_id varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  shift_start_time datetime NOT NULL,
  shift_replacement varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  shift_request_replacement varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

But I keep getting the error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I've tried to remove every `'` from the query itself (It fixed a previous issue once) but to no success this time.

The error is generated by these parts:

```
'2017-05-20 12:00:00.000000'
```

Does anyone know how to make this SQL query executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
 INSERT INTO shifts (shift_id, shift_facility_id, shift_user_id, shift_start_time, shift_replacement, shift_request_replacement) 
 VALUES
            (1, 57, '1', '2017-05-19 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
            (2, 57, '1', '2017-05-19 12:00:00', NULL, NULL),
            (3, 57, '1', '2017-05-20 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
            (4, 57, '1', '2017-05-20 12:00:00', NULL, NULL),
            (5, 57, '2', '2017-05-21 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
            (62, 59, '6', '2017-05-19 00:00:00', NULL, NULL)
            (64, 60, '4', '2017-05-19 00:00:00', NULL, NULL);
```

You have a `datetime` field, you do not need more precision than that so up to the minutes you should be OK.

Comment: .. or make shift_start_time a `datetime2` column.

Comment: if you can change the table structure... :)

Comment: Of course, but there _is_ a `CREATE TABLE` in the question :)

Comment: Cheers mate! Mvp :D